# ASP.NET MVC Project, Kendo Scheduler week view events are overlapping each other

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

In ASP.NET MVC Project i have Kendo Scheduler initialized, currently during week view the events are overlapping each other probably because of custom styling i applied.

The question is:

Is there a way to unbind events positioning from time? I need them to be ordered by time, but not positioned by time... So that each day column contains events set on this day, and to be displayed as a column of events, without positioning it according to time scale. First event of the day to take first cell of the day, second event - second cell, etc

[Here s a screenshot of the desired design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7OKl.png)

I have tried a lot of stuff, for example to have custom SlotTemplate, but then i have issues with getting events data inside it... there must be an easier and better way.